# Why is wrapping a React component inside a styled component a bad idea

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Referring to this post: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#when-should-i-use-styled

(and this: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1226#issuecomment-335240613)

Say you have a component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <div className={className}>Hello</div>;
    }
}
```

And you convert it into a styled component:

```
export default styled(MyComponent)`    
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center; 
`;
```

Why is this not a best practice?
Why is it better to simply use a styled component internally? Like so:

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return <MyStyledCmpt>Hello</MyStyledCmpt>;
    }
}

const MyStyledCmpt = styled.div`    
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center; 
`;
```

Please include an example of when it is a bad idea (if possible).

Comment: The links you provided are pretty clear why it is not the best practice. The main concern is spreading the UI logic across multiple elements. Why is it bad? Because it weakens one of the greatest strengths of styled components - encapsulation of styles. Having all in one place makes managing code (refactor, removal etc) easier.

Comment: @ŁukaszWojciechowski interesting. But at some point we will need to create a wrapper styled-component (eg. to style a list of smaller components). How is that different from wrapping the entire React component in a styled component?

Comment: @ŁukaszWojciechowski what I mean is: how is `render(){ return <MyWrapperStyledCmpt><SmallCmptList>...{even more components}</SmallCmptList></MyWrapperStyledCmpt>;}` any different from `styled(MyComponent)`;